# There's something not quite right with the achievements drop down on stackexchange.com (All of the site icons are wrong)

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

I just checked my (meagre) achievements for today on https://stackexchange.com/ and got this:

[image]

Where as it should look like this:

[image]

The site icons are a bit awry.

Comment: Inbox is OK, but network sites are also off. We are looking into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a bad version of a CSS file was cached (to do with the version hash we append) - causing this issue.

We fixed the version hash issue and purged the cache in the CDN, so should work as expected now (may require a hard refresh in the browser to see).

Comment: Yep. Ctrl+F5 and it's all good.

Comment: Hash Cash? Sounds good. :D

Comment: [Area51 needs some love too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302044/wrong-site-icons-are-displaying-in-area-51)