# Wrong site icons are displaying in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51, top-bar

I see the site icons are displaying wrongly in the Site switcher, inbox and achievements of the Area 51 main site.

I thought it is due to the cache, so pressed [Ctrl + F5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302027/theres-something-not-quite-right-with-the-achievements-drop-down-on-stackexchan#comment982268_302029) but still the same issue. When navigate to [Area 51 Meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), there I can see the new top bar and the icons are fine.

[image: Wrong site icons in Area 51]

Comment: Area51 runs on a different code base, whatever fix done on the other bug report should be deployed there as well. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In this case, the issue is with the CDN caching the topbar styles. It works the same on se.com and Area 51, so the same fix should apply.

Comment: @Adam so what went wrong?

Comment: @Arulkumar Try Ctrl+F5 now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably the same thing that goes wrong when this breaks. There's some sort of race in CDN cache when we do a prod build, and it's possible for a wrong old version to get cached for some nodes but not others. Super fun.

Comment: @AdamLear As I mentioned in the post, when I reported the issue, I tried with Ctrl + F5 but that not solved the issue. Anyway now it is not repro.

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes, because we purged the cache on our end. :)