# Wrong icon for chat top bar notices

Tags: bug, chat, design, top-bar

I recently got an answer upvote on an answer on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.  However, I ended up checking this on chat.stackexchange (specifically [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=anyway+gtg+o%2F&room=240), but it appears on main [chat.se](https://chat.stackexchange.com) too. Testing looks like favicons for multiple (at least 3) sites are not working.

Here is what it looks like on stackexchange.com (still old top bar, but no visual error):

[image: good image]

Here's what it looks like on chat.se:

[image: bad image]

I'm not entirely certain what that is? Looks like a meta icon for another site. If you look closely, you can see a tiny bit of the "PCG" icon just below it, but it's cut off.

This also happens on Literature notices, and Sci-fi and Fantasy (but not Vegetarianism or Veg.meta).  I don't have any meta notices to test with, other than the vegetarianism one (which is fine).

[image: more bad img]

I'm not providing an image, but this works with answer notices too. (tested with PPCG)

This is on Chrome (latest version, 61.0.3163.100) on OS X El Capitan.

[Related, same error on main sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302027/theres-something-not-quite-right-with-the-achievements-drop-down-on-stackexchan) (but tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) and [on A51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302044/wrong-site-icons-are-displaying-in-area-51) (unresolved).

Comment: I think that's the [CiviCRM meta](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/) logo.

Comment: Highly related  [There's something not quite right with the achievements drop down on stackexchange.com (All of the site icons are wrong)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302027/357396). This question got a [tag:status-completed].

Comment: Also for the same version of [Area 51 and it was completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302044/312043)

Comment: @Sinister it's still messed up today, and I tried clearing my cache.  It's serverside, whatever it is.

Comment: Wait... what is that weird icon to the right of the achievements icon?? Obviously not part of SE. Looks like you installed some userscript, which is likely messing things up. Remove this userscript and all should work just fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, tried that already. Still bugged even with that disabled.